# select records where regex equals other column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I've got a table whith integers in column A and strings in column B, like:

```
+---------+-----------------+
| columnA | columnB         | 
+---------+-----------------+
| 32      | 1,8,12,32       | <--
| 16      | 1,1,2,9,2,7     | 
| 321     | 3,10,56,111,321 | <--
+---------+-----------------+
```

Is there simple way to select rows where columnB ends with value from columnA?

Comment: `WHERE columnB LIKE CONCAT('%', t.columnA)`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: NO.  Most of the solutions, including the "dup", would incorrectly allow "21" to match the last case.  Suggesting reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Gordon's rant against storing a list that way.

`FIND_IN_SET()` checks for the integer being anywhere in the commalist.

`RIGHT()` won't check for a suitable boundary.  So, "21" would match "3,10,56,111,321".  As I understand the Question, only "321" should match.

`RIGHT()`, plus prefixing with a ',", would have "321" match "3,10,56,111,321" but fail with "321".

Before 8.0, "[[:<:]]321$" could be constructed to use as a regexp' `\\b` cannot be used.

MySQL 8.0 would not like the above regexp, but could use `"\\b321$"`.

So...

Plan A:  Combine some of the above tests and hope you have not left out an edge case.

Plan B:  Do as Gordon suggested:  fix the schema.

OK, I think this might be the shortest:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(colB, ',', -1) = colA

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('321', ',', -1) = '321';
+-----------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('321', ',', -1) = '321' |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       1 |
+-----------------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('321', ',', -1) = '21' |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
+-------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('7,321', ',', -1) = '321' |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('7,321,11', ',', -1) = '321' |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                            0 |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser, this edge case was valid in just 170 in around 1.3M results, but still VALID and btw. query execution time dropped from ~1000sec to ~60sec.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this question I got an idea for an anwser using concatenation.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE columnB REGEXP CONCAT(t.columnA, '$');
```

Comment: But "21" would satisfy the last case.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data model!  Do not store numbers as strings!  Do not store multiple values in a string column!

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other peoples really, really bad decisions.  MySQL has a useful function, `find_in_set()` for this case:

```
where find_in_set(columnA, columnB) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser, I'm working on translating an old database.

Comment: OP wants to check for at the end.